# Sorting a PHP Object array without keys?

Tags: php, object, usort

I am generating a list of cuisines like this:

```
$lists='';
$stmt="SELECT cuisine_id, cuisine_name, cuisine_name_trans FROM db_cuisine";

if ( $res=$DbExt->rst($stmt)){
    if ($list){
        foreach ($res as $val) {    

            $cuisine_json['cuisine_name_trans']=!empty($val['cuisine_name_trans'])?
            json_decode($val['cuisine_name_trans'],true):'';

            $lists[$val['cuisine_id']]="".qTranslate($val['cuisine_name'],'cuisine_name',$cuisine_json);
        }
        return $lists;
    }
    return $res;
}       
return false;
```

The list is then returned as:

```
1: "American"
5: "Sandwiches"
6: "Barbeque"
8: "Italian"
9: "Mexican"
10: "Sushi"
11: "Burgers"
13: "Japanese"
```

(The `IDs` are according to the database ID). I am trying to sort them now `descending by name` but I can't seem to get it done with `sort` as it needs a key name. How do I do that?

Comment: What are `$list`, `$cuisine_json` and `$lists`? Where are they defined? What does `qTranslate()` do?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that. `$list` is just a true/false. `$lists` is defined with `$lists='';` and `$cuisine_json` comes from `cuisine_name_trans`.

Comment: This question need significant improvement if you are to get it to a state where it contains a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: instead of converting the row data to output string directly, store it as array key=>value first. after the loop is exited, do an asort() and then json_encode() to convert it as json string.

Comment: If `$lists` is a string, you're going to run in to problems with that `$lists[$val['cuisine_id']]` bit. I'd recommend an array instead, ie `$lists = [];`

Comment: Looks like I will need to rewrite the whole code there and take a different approach. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Do Sorting with sql instead of php

```
$stmt="SELECT cuisine_id, cuisine_name, cuisine_name_trans FROM db_cuisine WHERE 1 ORDER BY cuisine_name DESC ";
```

Comment: I tried that but somehow it's not working. As to why, that's beyond me. So I'm trying to get it done with PHP...

Comment: And since I use translations after retrieving it, the sorting may differ.

Comment: in your code you are  sorting the array before translate.So i think its not affect the translate function

Comment: And `if($list)` is always false.So its not passing to the statment

Comment: Looks like I will need to rewrite the whole code there and take a different approach. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) function. It sorts an array by value in the descending order. Your final code should be like:

```
if ( $res=$DbExt->rst($stmt)){
    if ($list){
        foreach ($res as $val) {    

            $cuisine_json['cuisine_name_trans']=!empty($val['cuisine_name_trans'])?
            json_decode($val['cuisine_name_trans'],true):'';

            $lists[$val['cuisine_id']]="".qTranslate($val['cuisine_name'],'cuisine_name',$cuisine_json);
        }
        arsort($lists);
        return $lists;
    }
    return $res;
}       
return false;
```

I also recommend to check [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) to get more info about the PHP array sort functions.